# Image in between products in magento category page

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I need to show a static image in between magento category products.Any suggestions??? Kindly help

reference HOW DID WE DO? banner in this link
http://www.frenchconnection.com/category/Woman+Collections+Dresses/Dresses.htm

Answer (score 0):

Create a yes or no attribute(show_image_only) in admin, drag the created attribute in required attribute set.
and  save. then for a product which you want show only image set the attribute(show image only) as yes. then in list.phtml write an condition if show image only is yes. then show only product image . thats it.